# Cisco APIC `show version` formatting

Tags: cisco

Whenever I issue `show version` command in Cisco APIC, I'm getting weird output like this.

Not sure why the hostname of controller `AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC-0001` is separated into 2 lines which make the output very weird.

The same thing goes with other hostname as well

**Actual Output**

```
AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC_0001# show version 

 Role        Pod         Node        Name                      Version              
 ----------  ----------  ----------  ------------------------  -------------------- 
 controller  1           1           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_        3.2(4e)              
                                     APC-0001                                       
 controller  2           2           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_        3.2(4e)              
                                     APC-0002                                       
 controller  3           3           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_        3.2(4e)              
                                     APC-0003                                       
 spine       1           111         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_01  n9000-13.2(4e)       
                                     11                                             
 spine       1           112         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_01  n9000-13.2(4e)       
                                     12                                             
 spine       1           113         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_01  n9000-13.2(4e)       
                                     13                                             
 leaf        1           1101        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_11  n9000-13.2(4e)       
                                     01                                             
 leaf        1           1102        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_11  n9000-13.2(4e)       
                                     02                                             
 leaf        1           1103        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_11  n9000-13.2(4e)       
                                     03
```

Is there a way to fix this?

**Desired Output**

```
AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC_0001# show version 

 Role        Pod         Node        Name                        Version              
 ----------  ----------  ----------  ------------------------    -------------------- 
 controller  1           1           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC_0001        3.2(4e)
 controller  2           2           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC_0002        3.2(4e)                                   
 controller  3           3           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC_0003        3.2(4e)                                   
 spine       1           111         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_0111  n9000-13.2(4e)                          
 spine       1           112         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_0112  n9000-13.2(4e)                            
 spine       1           113         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_0113  n9000-13.2(4e)                            
 leaf        1           1101        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_1101  n9000-13.2(4e)                            
 leaf        1           1102        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_1102  n9000-13.2(4e)                            
 leaf        1           1103        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_1103  n9000-13.2(4e)
```

Comment: The only thing you can try is to change the terminal width, but I doubt that will solve the problem.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something on what you can't affect from your side. I suppose the best option will be to create a support ticket with a feature request. But there is a really small chance that Cisco will do something with it. I have multiple examples when more problematic cases were marked as "wont-fix".

I have this output by the way:

```
# show version
 Role        Pod         Node        Name                      Version
 ----------  ----------  ----------  ------------------------  --------------------
 controller  1           1           XXXXXX-DC-APIC-1          4.0(3d)
 controller  1           2           XXXXXX-DC-APIC-2          4.0(3d)
 controller  1           3           XXXXXX-DC-APIC-3          4.0(3d)
 leaf        1           101         XXXXXX-DC-LEAF-101        n9000-14.0(3d)
 leaf        1           102         XXXXXX-DC-LEAF-102        n9000-14.0(3d)
 leaf        1           103         XXXXXX-DC-LEAF-103        n9000-14.0(3d)
 leaf        1           104         XXXXXX-DC-LEAF-104        n9000-14.0(3d)
 leaf        1           105         XXXXXX-DC-LEAF-105        n9000-14.0(3d)
 leaf        1           106         XXXXXX-DC-LEAF-106        n9000-14.0(3d)
 spine       1           201         XXXXXX-DC-SPINE-201       n9000-14.0(3d)
 spine       1           202         XXXXXX-DC-SPINE-202       n9000-14.0(3d)
```

Comment: I guess this problem is caused by the length of the hostname.